# inconsistent treatment of class template with defaulted argument as template template class argument of smaller arity

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer, template-meta-programming

The following snippet is rejected by Clang on C++17, accepted by GCC on C++17 and rejected by GCC on C++14. This is consistent with all recent compiler versions. What's the correct behavior ?

```
template <class T, class = int>
struct test1 {};

template <class T, template <class> class>
struct test2 {};

using test_t = test2<int, test1>;
```

EDIT: Apparently this is actually implemented on Clang, it just needs an explicit flag: `-frelaxed-template-template-args` which is not included when using `-pedantic`.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to include the error messages produced in the failing cases into the question.

Comment: Since I found the report I could search more about the issue and it turns out that this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC's *is* the correct behavior. It is consistent with [p0522r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0522r0.html), which was accepted into C++17.

From the paper's introduction:

> Template template-parameters only bind to arguments with matching
> parameter lists. Matching is currently defined as an exact match; each
> template parameter in the argument's parameter list must have the same
> kind and type as the corresponding parameter in the
> template-parameter's parameter list. (There is an ill-advised
> exception to this rule when a parameter pack appears in the
> template-parameter's parameter list; this paper preserves that special
> behavior.) The matching rules exclude many reasonable arguments. This
> paper adjusts the matching rules to invoke partial ordering to
> determine when a template template-argument is a valid match for a
> template-parameter.

The paper also contains code examples of what will change, and this snippet is very much like the example whose behavior you observed:

```
template <template <typename> class> void FD();
template <typename, typename = int> struct SD { /* ... */ };
FD<SD>();  // OK; error before this paper (CWG 150)
```

Comment: @LiarokapisAlexandros - Clang reports to support this feature since version 4. It may be a bug or a regression.

Comment: Apparently this is actually implemented on Clang, it just needs an explicit flag: `-frelaxed-template-template-args`. Not sure if it's the right decision to not include this when using `-pedantic` though.

Comment: @LiarokapisAlexandros - I believe the clang devs had concerns this will break existing code since overload resolution would essentially work differently now. Can't really fault them there. But an informational diagnostic would have been nice.